# Python: How do I use DictReader twice?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

This feels like a very basic question, but I can't find any mention of it elsewhere. I'm a beginning Python user.

When I read in data using DictReader, and then use the dictionary, I'm unable to reference it again. For example, using this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "<head><title>Title</title></head><body>"

f = open("blurbs.csv","rb")
blurbs = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter="\t")
for row in blurbs:
    print row
for row in blurbs:
    print row

f.close()
print "</body>"
```

Will only print out the contents of blurbs.csv once. The second "for row in blurbs:" does nothing. Is there something I'm missing? How can I make the dictionary into something I can reference repeatedly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need to seek the file back to the start:

```
with open("blurbs.csv","rb") as f:
    blurbs = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for row in blurbs:
        print row
    f.seek(0)
    for row in blurbs:
        print row
```

Alternatively you can wrap the dictionary generation into a list of dicts and operate on that:

```
with open("blurbs.csv","rb") as f:
    blurbs = list(csv.DictReader(f, delimiter="\t"))
for row in blurbs:
    print row
for row in blurbs:
    print row
```

Comment: This doesn't really "make the dictionary into something I can reference repeatedly"

Comment: Added an alternative that addresses that second question.

Answer (score 8):

In Python (and almost all computer languages), if you want to store something, you have to do that explicitly. Just printing it out doesn't keep it around anywhere except on the screen.

To use *each* dictionary repeatedly, but only one at a time, that's easy; `row` is *already* storing each dictionary, one at a time:

```
for row in blurbs:
    print row
    print row
    print row
```

---

To use *all* of the dictionaries repeatedly, you need to store *all* of them somewhere.

They *are* already in `blurbs`, but `blurbs` is an [*iterator*](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator)—something you can loop over once. Once you finish it, there's nothing left in it. That's why your second loop prints nothing.

You want a [*sequence*](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-sequence)—something you can index, search, loop over dozens of times, etc. The obvious sequence type to use, when there are no special cases to worry about, is a list. So:

```
with open("blurbs.csv","rb") as f:
    blurbs = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter="\t")
    rows = list(blurbs)

for row in rows:
    print row
print rows[13]
for row in rows:
    print row
print sorted(rows)
```

---

The Tutorial section on [Iterators](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) and the following sections explain some of this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to re-use the reader, you could seek the file back to 0. But, if the first row int the csv are headings, then that will be part of the output:

```
>>> f = open( 'file.csv', 'rbU' )
>>> reader = csv.DictReader( f )
>>> reader.next()
{'col1': '6', 'col2': '0.9', 'col3': '8'}
>>> f.seek(0)
>>> reader.next()
{'col1': 'col1', 'col2': 'col2', 'col3': 'col3'}
>>> f.close()
```

DictReader uses the first row as the dictionary keys (if they are not otherwise supplied). Creating a new reader object is a lot simpler. You can also copy the data into a data structure like a list and loop over that.